# How do I create a Module(class) in react native using .ts file and use it in app

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to create a class like below

FirstClass.ts file

```
export class FirstClass{
  name:String
  id:String

  constructor(name:String,id:String){
    this.name=name
    this.id=id
  }
}
```

above class is in models package.

Use this class in '.js' file to create object of that class.

I tried to import it like below.

```
import FirstClass from '@models/FirstClass'
```

and inside function called like below.

```
new FirstClass('xyz','001')
```

i get error like 'undefined is not a constructor(evaluating 'new _FirstClass.FirstClass('xyz','001')'

Comment: You need to export `FirstClass` from the file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is covered in quick start and the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: Why did you get a vote on my answer?

Comment: Thank you @JaredSmith it helped I was exporting the class, but was using 'export default'  when i removed 'default' everything worked as it suppose to be. Thanks